# Can i add an API for a normal view function without performing any operations on viewsets in djnago

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

suppose i created a model of blog an performed **CRUD operations on it without API** and now i want to add an **API to that model** without performing operations in view-sets. Whenever an data is passed through API or our site model it should display in db and on front end. Is it possible??

thanks,in advance

Comment: its possible. Checkout DRF's documentation

Answer (score 0):

That's covered by the [step 3 of the Django REST framework's tutorial](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/)